# How to install the 'glob' module?

Tags: python, glob, ros

I am running ubuntu 14.04 and trying to launch ROS Simulator. I have this error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'glob'
```

Installing glob2 does not solve the problem.

`python -m site` output:

```
sys.path = [
    '/home/omar',
    '/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
    '/home/omar/anaconda3/lib/python35.zip',
    '/home/omar/anaconda3/lib/python3.5',
    '/home/omar/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/plat-linux',
    '/home/omar/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload',
    '/home/omar/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages',
    '/home/omar/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/Sphinx-1.4.6-py3.5.egg',
    '/home/omar/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numba-0.29.0-py3.5-linux-x86_64.egg',
    '/home/omar/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/glob2-0.4.1-py3.5.egg',
    '/home/omar/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools-27.2.0-py3.5.egg',
]
USER_BASE: '/home/omar/.local' (exists)
USER_SITE: '/home/omar/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages' (doesn't exist)
ENABLE_USER_SITE: True
```

Comment: `glob` is a standard module. Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: Python 3.5.2 
Some solutions recommended reinstalling Ubuntu, but i'm keeping that as plan B.

Comment: Please include the output of `python -m site`

Comment: @wim I added it to the question

Comment: glob is part of the Standard Library in Python so you do not need to install it

Comment: The accepted answer is wrong. See the comments on the accepted answer.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

For python 2.7:
`pip install glob2`

For python 3.7:
`pip3 install glob2`

Comment: You really shouldn't sudo install packages for security purposes.

Comment: even for pip3 it's still glob2, not glob3 :-D

Comment: @SkylerWiernik what are the security concerns of using sudo for installation?

Comment: @PedroMartinez you are giving the installation scripts of the package you are installing route access. If you were to install a malicious package (through something such as a type-o) you could potentially give hackers full access to your entire machine.

Comment: this answer is wrong, three comments with valid concerns but missing the point, and one being even wronger than the answer. ***Python has a `glob` module built-in.*** if it's missing, the Python installation is broken and needs fixing. ***DO NOT*** install a random third-party package to "fix" this.

Answer (score 4):

For Python 3, there is no `glob3`.

So use:

```
sudo pip3 install glob2
```

Comment: You *should* not do sudo pip install. `pip3 install package_name` works fine.

Comment: the sudo isn't the issue. `glob` is part of the standard library. it should never be missing.

Answer (score 1):

ROS does not support Python 3 in the first place, so I would not recommend you use it. You should install 2.7.

Redownload it: https://www.python.org/downloads/

Here's the source for glob: https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html

As you can see it's in the Lib package which marks it as standard

Comment: this is the first sensible answer. all the others don't even wonder why a module from the standard library seems to be missing.

Answer (score 1):

In Python version 3.10, the [glob module](https://www.alixaprodev.com/2021/08/how-to-use-python-glob-module.html) is included in the standard module list. It means you do not need to install it.

You might be facing this error because you are using any prior version of python.

In this case use

```
pip3 install glob2
```

But make sure you have to import it using

```
import glob 
# not import glob2
```

Hope this helped.

Happy Globbing.

Comment: this is even worse. the `glob` module has been with Python since almost forever. this is certainly not an issue that showed up in 2022. nor should anyone just recommend installing any random third-party package to "fix" a broken Python installation.

Answer (score -1):

`pip3 install glob2` and then refresh
it basically.
If you're referring to a "global module" in Python, it's possible you're referring to a module that is accessible throughout your entire program, rather than being limited to a specific scope or function. In Python, you can create global modules by defining variables, functions, or classes at the top level of your script or module.

Here's an example of how you can define a global variable in a module:

```py
# mymodule.py

global_var = 10

def my_function():
    print("This is a global function.")

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        print("This is a global class.")
```

In the above example, `global_var`, `my_function()`, and `MyClass` are all accessible throughout the module and can be imported and used in other parts of your program.

To use the global variables, functions, or classes defined in your module, you can import the module into your script or another module using the `import` statement:

```py
# main.py

import mymodule

print(mymodule.global_var)  # Output: 10

mymodule.my_function()  # Output: This is a global function.

obj = mymodule.MyClass()  # Output: This is a global class.
```

By importing the `mymodule`, you can access and utilize the global entities defined within it.

I hope this helps! Let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: completely missing the mark. "glob" has nothing to do with global variables AND you just recommended installing a random third party package without any justification.

Answer (score -2):

if you use Linux Distributions write this command:

```
sudo pip install glob2
```

for python 3:

```
sudo pip3 install glob2
```

and if you using Windows:
open a command prompt and write this command:

```
pip install glob2
```

for python 3:

```
pip3 install glob
```

Comment: You shouldn't sudo install anything, that's a bad practice and a security risk.

Comment: I try that on some distributions and get (Access Denied) Error.